# Delete and update AspectJ markers doesn't respond in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, aspectj, spring-roo

I've created a web mvc json project using spring roo in eclipse. I have STS suite and my eclipse version is kepler. I've enabled aspectj spring tooling in my project. Whenever I make any change and save it eclipse starts to build workspace which runs fine. But after that the spring suite executes bookkeeping operations to update the aspectj configuration and create new classes. There is one such book keeping process in progress bar-"Delete and update Aspectj markers for $project_name$" which doesn't not respond. Because of this process all other processes pile up pretty quickly and then eclipse application stops responding. Does anyone know what this process does or what can cause it to hang and how to fix it? Really want to avoid toying around with eclipse because then it eats too much time to fix it if it is broken.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't solve this problem. Eventually I had to delete the project from workspace and restart from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

According to Spring Roo documentation you should not try edit ITD aspects generated by Spring Roo. Roo tries to update the information whenever the Roo command line is running or when you open the project. It might take long time if the project size is bigger and you have changed many things. This might be the case with you. My suggestion you should wait while Spring Roo completes the housekeeping operations.

If you want to change the functionalities that is present inside the aspects you have to define that method inside the class. Spring Roo will delete the unnecessary aspect itself. if you want to delete those, don't delete manually. Just create the method with the same name.

To remove automatically generated getters/setters you can remove the `@RooJavaBean`. If you want to remove toString method you can remove `@RooToString` and so on. You can identify Roo generated annotations by seeing its name it starts with `@Roo`.

According to Roo documentation there are following recommended practice

> - Don't edit any files that Roo code generates (see the Usability    Philosophy for details).
> - Before installing any new technology,    check if Roo offers a setup command and use it if present (this will    ensure the seutp reflects
>     our recommendations and the expectations of    other add-ons).
> - Ensure you leave the Roo shell running when    creating, updating or deleting files in your project.
> - Remember you'll still need to write Java code (and JSPs for custom controllers). Have the right expectations before you start using Roo. 
>     It just helps you - it doesn't replace the requirement to program.
> - Check the Known Issues section before upgrading or if you experience any problems.
> - Refer to the Roo Resources section for details of how to get assistance with Roo, such as the forum and  issue tracking database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! After searching over the internet I found that eclipse aspectj plugin Deletes and Updates all the AspectJ markers in the project every time some change is made to the aspects by roo. I have increased the memory for eclipse and wait for it to do its thing as it takes long due to size of the project.